# File not found 404 Error should be thrown using AngularJS when the user enter the invalid webpage url after login into the webpage

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to throw 404 error when the user enter the invalid url after permitting the user to the webpage. For an example home is the login page and I am allowing the user to login to the page as( home/ )and I can throw the 404 error. After login to the page the user enter url called (/employee) and I am struggling in throwing 404 error when the user enter (/employee/invalid url). Can anyone guide me how to do that and my code is here:

app.run(function ($rootScope, $window, $location, SessionService, $cookies, $cookieStore) {

```
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, nextRoute, currentRoute) {

    var currentpath = $location.path();
    currentpath = currentpath.split('/');
    if (currentpath[1] === "") {
        $location.path("/home");
    }
    else if (currentpath[1] === "employee") {
        if ((nextRoute.access && nextRoute.access.requiredLogin) && !$window.sessionStorage.boid) {

            $location.path("/employee");
        }
    }
    else if (currentpath[1] === "department") {
        if ((nextRoute.access && nextRoute.access.requiredLogin) && !$window.sessionStorage.retailerid) {
            $location.path("/department");
        }
    } else
    {
        $location.path("/404.html");
    }

});
```

});
 The above code throw the 404 only for (/employee) and not for  (/employee/invalid url)

Comment: Shouldn't you be checking against the nextRoute argument passed to the function instead of $location.path() (the current path)?

Comment: Why does the above code throw 404 page for `/employee` route ? Are you sure it does ? `/employee` should match with second `if(..)` construct and either it should redirect user to `/employee` or do nothing.